# Share a Feed with FBNativeDialog

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I wanna share a feed with parameter below by using `FBNativeDialog`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   link, @"link",
                                   url, @"picture",
                                   strText, @"message",
                                   @"name", @"name",
                                   nil];
```

I saw the Dialog does not support like this, but is there any way to do it?

P/s: should use Dialog, then User can input their message also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `SLComposeViewController`

```
SLComposeViewController *composerVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:
                                               SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [composerVC addURL:someUrl];
        [composerVC addImage:someImage];
        [composerVC setInitialText:someText];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple web view and show feed like

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/"];
theURL = [theURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *response;
response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
if (err != nil)
{
   //write some thing
}
else
{
          NSURL *url;
       url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.facebook.com/UwMadisonConfessions?fref=ts"];



    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```